# Unable to hide an image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to hide some images for my computer science project but it won't seem to work anyone know why?

Heres the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fitness Programs</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <!-- program choices -->
   <img src ="cardio.jpg" width ="350" height="200" id="cardio">
   <img src ="hiit.jpg" width = "350" height="200" class="hiit">
   <img src ="strength.jpg" width = "350" height="200" class="strength">
   <img src ="toning.jpg" width = "350" height="200" class="toning">

</body>
</html>
```

Heres the Javascript

```
// hide images
document.getElementById("cardio").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("hiit").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("strength").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("toning").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Please correct your attribute name from `class` to `id`

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugging tools in your browser. There would be helpful error messages if you have looked at the Console in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: I did look in the console and nothing showed

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you are giving the first element and `id` and the rest a `class`

your code tells the browser to hide the elements that has an `id` of `cardio`,`hiit`,`strength` and `toning`.
the browser looks for these elements and finds only `cardio` and hides it the reset does not because you are giving them a `class` insted of `id`, 
so there is 2 ways of solving this issue,

1) change `class` to `id` and the code will work

2) you change the `cardio` id to `class` and implement the code in use case 2.

#### example of use case 1

```
<img src ="cardio.jpg" width ="350" height="200" id="cardio">
<img src ="hiit.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="hiit">
<img src ="strength.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="strength">
<img src ="toning.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="toning">
```

### exmaple of use case 2

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hiit");
for(var i =0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Read More About [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: There is no element with `class="cardio"`

Comment: @Quentin updated

Comment: The code in the question fails before running into any problems caused by confusing class and id.

Comment: @Quentin the code works, the problem i did't explain the problem, i'll update the answer

Comment: @Quentin how about now?

Comment: You've still missed the primary problem. See the duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin the duplicate explains why this would happen but does not explain the mistake or the fail try of the question, he looks like he missed/forgot to change `class` to `id` or he does not understand the way of element searching, the duplicate answer this after you get to understand the functionality of `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: The class/id confusion is a different error that would be encountered later (after the primary problem is solved).

Comment: @Quentin i can agree with you on that since the title is `Unable to hide` and the dupliate you provided answer a cases where this issue could happen, but the questioner attempt to achive the goal he wants diffrent from the duplicate answer has

Comment: No. It isn't. The `<script>` element in the question appears before the elements the script tries to modify.

Comment: @Quentin Right, this is an issue, and the answer i provided solves the second issue, this code has 2 problems the duplicate answer you provided does not solve the entire issue, (the code will still not work)

Comment: @Quentin would you re-consider marking this as duplicate?

Comment: No I understand the class/id difference I had been editing the code many different ways to make it work so forgot to change it back so that it was all the same. Anyway I have tried both class and id and still can’t get it working